# How can you design a script that is prepared to take varied possible quantity of arguments as argv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argv

When you give a function a set of needed arguments or assign argv, the code demands that you give the correct number of args or it goes on to give, "expected number of things to unpack from a tuple is wrong", sorts of errors.

But I use scripts everyday that are very dynamic in how specifically the arguments can be given and in which types orders, etc.

I eventually imagine making scripts with a --help switch that list all the possible argv and options you can add, but for now as I am beginning, lets keep it **very**, *somewhat* simple:

I want the following to not raise error and to not EXPECT arguments to be given but to take them when they are there:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from sys import argv

script, verbose_option, user_input = argv

if "verbose" in verbose_option:
    verbose_option = True
else:
    verbose_option = False

x = value
if verbose_option == True:
    print("var x is set to value...")
else:
    pass

if user_input == True: # if true, the var contains any value, correct?
    print(user_input)
else:
    print("user_input not given but, ... no problem!")
    user_input = input("> ") # or maybe it has a default value that can be changed from argv

if verbose_option == True:
    print("Would I really need this conditional on every line I left a verbose explanation on?")
else:
    pass
```

Somehow it has to know that user_input is not intended as verbose just because verbose isn't there, so... maybe a conditional branch that tests the `len()` of the tuple of arguments and figures, "well, that must be this and not that based on that number. OR.... is that overly complex and there is a better way?

This is a less important: how messy a verbose option must make the code if there isn't a better way than I imagined in the example code, but that's a bonus question. I want to not error and have default values for things or means of getting the data if not given as argv despite being able to be taken as argv.

Comment: This is much better handled using a library like [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) or [`Click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/)

Comment: beware that you've got a typo in your example `user_input = True` is not valid ;)

Comment: @zmo Thank you for pointing that out. I actually wasn't sure if that passed as an acceptable Boolean expression or not How would you phrase the bool expression, "if has any value" then?

Comment: The typo is in the fact that you use an assignment in an if condition expression. it should be `if user_input == True`. Given the way you set it up, the fact that you did not get an exception at assignment shows that the variable contains a value (the assignment of three variables on the left hand side excepts a list of length 3). A variable in python always contains a value (even if the value is `None`). Whether the value is valid is another thing, and shall be checked explicitely. `user_input == True` checks that the variable `user_input` containing a thruthy boolean, nothing else.

Comment: @zmo I can't believe I overlooked that :P Fixed. But, I didn't know that about variables. Is perhaps `if user_input:` more what I should have put to mean what I was trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the arguments that way:

```
def handle_arguments(argv):
    env = {'user_input': []}
    for arg in argv:
        if arg in ['-v', '--verbose']
            env['verbose'] = True
        elif arg in ['-h', '--help']
            display_help()
            sys.exit(0)
        else
            env['user_input'] += [arg]

    if length(env['user_input']) == 0
        env['user_input'] = input('> ')
    else
        env['user_input'].join(' ')

    return env
```

there you've got a function that takes arguments and returns a well formed `env` variable.

So then you can pass sys.argv to handle_arguments by removing the useless sys.argv[0] (useless in this context)

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = handle_arguments(sys.argv[1:])
    do_stuff(**env)
```

where stuff is either a function with the following prototype:

```
def do_stuff(user_input='', verbose=False):
```

or you can make it take any argument:

```
def do_stuff(**kwargs):
```

That being said, it's more or less the basic inner working of an argument parsing library. And to make it right, expectable by CLI users, you'd better use one, like [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/), [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) or my personal favourite [docopt](https://docopt.org).

Comment: Thank you for giving me multiple things to think about. The concept of an `env` variable is one I haven't read much on, but I will. The only env variables I know are the BASH ones like $PATH and $HOME. I don't know why I didn't assume there would be specific libs for this that I had not yet encountered, but trying to solve problems with code that you know before you move on to better ways seems to be how I have learned what I do know.

Comment: naming that variable `env` is just a conventional way to store all the data that makes up the environment of your algorithm. You could call it however you like (`context`, `params`...), but using that convention shows the intent: provide some environmental settings (things provided outside of the code) to set up your code. The shell's env (you can get through `os.environ`) expresses the same concept (things provide outside of the code). So `env` is no magic, it's just a variable that's fully under *your* control! 

Comment: Finally, don't be afraid of using libraries, you will learn a lot by implementing them, and reading their source code (and the thinking that went to build them). And doing so, will help you focus on what you're trying to achieve and the learning path you're following doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's some arg parsing packages out there, but, if you want to do it from scratch, you could try something like:

```
args = sys.argv
if args:
    #Verbose would be a boolean, true if -v in args, false if not
    verbose = '-v' in args
    #Same thing here, making a boolean based on existence
    help = '--help' in args
    #Here we are assuming the arg after '-x' is some variable we want to store
    x = args[args.index('-x') + 1] if '-x' in args else None
```

For your conditionals, if 'verbose' is a boolean, you only need to use:

```
if verbose:
   do_something
```

Or you could do something like:

```
print('Hello') if verbose else None
```

Comment: Thank you for that last line especially, which I was wondering what the shortest form syntax you could use to use to have the conditional. I didn't know it could be written like this. I'm still very new if you didn't notice and still am reading my first programing (LP3THW) book. So... I'll have to apologize for asking for a "comment out translation" (that's what I call explaining syntax I don't yet know well in plan English) `  x = args[args.index('-x') + 1] if '-x' in args else None`, which is the only part I'm not sure about. Is `args` a list? Was it before this line?

Comment: Yes, 'args' is tied to 'sys.argv' which in your code is equivalent to 'argv'
So, the line that assigns 'x' is looking through the list for the index of '-x' in the list, then adding one, assuming the next arg is the variable that should be 'x'. Using the 'if else' statement "short-circuits" if '-x' is not in args so we don't hit an exception with args.index, and instead assigns None to 'x'.
"short-circuiting" comes from python's lazy evaluation of "if else" statements, in this case "if '-x' in args" is False, then "args[args.index('-x') + 1]" won't be evaluated.